# Best practices for debugging vagrant+docker+flask

Tags: python, flask, vagrant, docker

My goal is to run a flask webserver from a Docker container. Working on a Windows machine this requires Vagrant for creating a VM. Running vagrant up --provider=docker leads to the following complaint:

```
INFO interface: error: The container started either never left the "stopped" state or
very quickly reverted to the "stopped" state. This is usually
because the container didn't execute a command that kept it running,
and usually indicates a misconfiguration.

If you meant for this container to not remain running, please
set the Docker provider configuration "remains_running" to "false":

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
     d.remains_running = false
  end
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mrmrcoleman/python_webapp

EXPOSE 5000

# Install Python 
RUN apt-get install -y python python-dev python-distribute python-pip

# Add and install Python modules
RUN pip install Flask

#copy the working directory to the container
ADD . /

CMD python run.py
```

And this is the Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "." #searches for a local dockerfile

  end
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
  rsync__chown = false
end
```

Because the Vagrantfile and run.py work without trouble independently, I suspect I made a mistake in the Dockerfile. My question is twofold:

1. Is there something clearly wrong with the Dockerfile or the
   Vagrantfile?
2. Is there a way to have vagrant/docker produce more
   specific error messages?

Comment: does `python run.py` start a daemon or is this program running in the foreground ? If it runs a daemon, then the docker container will stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer I was looking for is using the command

```
vagrant docker-logs
```

I broke the Dockerfile because I did not recognize good behaviour as such, because nothing really happens if the app runs as it should. docker-logs confirms that the flask app is listening for requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something clearly wrong with the Dockerfile or the Vagrantfile?

Your Dockerfile and Vagrantfiles look good, but I think you need to modify the permissions of run.py to be executable:

```
...
#copy the working directory to the container
ADD . /
RUN chmod +x run.py

CMD python run.py
```

Does that work?

> Is there a way to have vagrant/docker produce more specific error messages?

Try taking a look at the [vagrant debugging page](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html). Another approach I use is to log into the container and try running the script manually.

```
# log onto the vm running docker
vagrant ssh

# start your container in bash, assuming its already built. 
docker run -it my/container /bin/bash

# now from inside your container try to start your app
python run.py
```

Also, if you want to view your app locally, you'll want to add [port forwarding](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html) to your Vagrantfile.